# How to check plugin compatibility before upgrading Wordpress

Tags: plugins, upgrade

When you're upgrading a plugin you can quickly check if the plugin version you are about to upgrade to works with your current version of Wordpress. Is there a way of checking that your current plugins will work with the version of Wordpress you are about it upgrade to without searching for each one in the directory?

Comment: Use this plugin to check the plugin compatibality with the lastest version of WordPress before upgrading Wordpress
https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-compatibility-checker/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a glance at [Better Plugin Compatibility Control](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-plugin-compatibility-control/). I just found this out this morning. I think this does what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

@Brady's plugin is exactly what you are asking for, and I use it too, but just to list another plugin that is handy when you are updating plugins is the [Changelogger](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/changelogger/) plugin. It can show you what has changed between your current plugin version and the update that is available.